# Cin Questions in Examples of Accelerated C++

Tags: c++, cin

I am working through a simple example in Chapter 4 of Accelerated C++ and getting confused with the way that cin works. The basic frameworks is defining a struct called student_info and then use cin to get grades of final, midterm and homework. The code I am playing with is as following:

```
struct Student_info{
    string name;
    double midterm, final;
    vector<double> homework;
};

istream& read_hw(istream& in, vector<double>& hw){
    double x;
    if (in){
        cout << "Please input your homework.";
        hw.clear();
        while (in >> x){
            hw.push_back(x);
        }
        in.clear();
    }
    return in;
}
istream& read(istream& in, Student_info& s){
    cout << "Please input your name, final, and midterm.";
    in >> s.name >> s.final >> s.midterm;
    read_hw(in,s.homework);
    return in;
}

int main(void){
    Student_info record;
    vector<Student_info> students;
    while (read(cin, record)){
        students.push_back(record);
    }

    while (read(cin, record)) {
        // find length of longest name
        students.push_back(record);
    }
    cout << students[0].name;
    cout << students[1].name;

    system("pause");
}
```

I expect that every time if I finish entering homework, the cout will pop up and tell me to enter the name, final and midterm for a new record. However, I have the following output:

```
Please input your name, final, and midterm.a
100
200
Please input your homework.100
200
300
b
Please input your name, final, and midterm.100
200
Please input your homework.100
200
300
400
/0
Please input your name, final, and midterm.s
Please input your name, final, and midterm.ab
```

After I entered b, I expect the the program will first pop up the message to ask me for the name. But it seems that the program had take the b as the input for name as first, then pop up the message.

How can I fix this?

Thank you for all your help!

Xi

Comment: After clearing the stream, I think you need to ignore any remaining characters in it. `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max());`

Comment: `read_hw` reads numbers in a loop until it reads something that it can't parse as a number. Then it gets out of the loop and leaves the "bad" character in the input strteam. The next input operation re-reads the same character again.

Comment: @NeilKirk, I tried your cin.ignore and it works.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, with your answer, now I understand the way cin works! Do you mind answering this question? I'll accept your answer.